# Bitwise check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I play a game, and in the database we set 100663296 to be a GM Leader but also this field in the database gets written to for different things, so it changes that number to 100794368
i was told to possible use a `bit-wise check` to check whether the first number is the same as the second number, and I have googled on using `bit-wise checks` but got confused as to what to use for my check.

Here are some other numbers that change, including the one from above.

```
predefined number   new changed number/ever changing number.
100663296       =       100794368
67108864        =       67239936
117440512       =       2231767040
```

so how should i go about checking these numbers?

And here is part of my code that i was using before i noticed the change in the numbers.

```
if (playerData[i].nameflags == 67108864) 
{ 
    playerRows += '<img src ="icons/GM-Icon.png" alt="GM" title="GM"></img>';
}
```

thx to Bergi, for the answer.

```
    if (playerData[i].nameflags & 0x400000 /* === 0x400000 */)
```

this seams to work great.

also thx to vr1911428
and every one else for the help on this.

Comment: If you don't have all the possible bit masks values and their meanings it will be a little hard to do said check I believe.

Comment: I don't get it. The condition of 12345 to be = 12666 is because of 12=12?

Comment: Fabrico is right.  At the very lest you need to know which bit you're looking for in the mask.

Comment: "*but also this field in the database gets written to for different things*" is the root cause for your issue. Change that and profit :-)

Comment: Yes, @Aurand is correct. Knowing the bit would greatly help. If you're developing for them, it'd be expected for them to provide you with the meaning of the mask at least. I agree with Bergi, that looks like bad DB design, but it might be out of OP's scope to rewrite that if the system is already working like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's convert those numbers to binary representation (unsigned integer):

```
> 100663296
00000110000000000000000000000000
> 100794368
00000110000000100000000000000000
> 67108864
00000100000000000000000000000000
> 67239936
00000100000000100000000000000000
> 117440512
00000111000000000000000000000000
> 2231767040
10000101000001100001000000000000
```

Notice that the last number is out of the scope of [JavaScripts bitwise arithmetic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), which only works with 32-bit *signed* integers - you won't be able to use the leftmost bit.

So which bits do you want to compare now? There are lots of possibilities, the above scheme doesn't make it clear, yet it looks like you are looking for the 27th bit from the right (2<sup>26</sup> = 67108864). To match against it, you can apply a binary AND bitmask:

```
x & Math.pow(2, 26)
```

which should evaluate to 2<sup>26</sup> again or zero - so you can just check for truthiness. Btw, instead of using `pow` you could use hexadecimal notation: `0x4000000`. With that, your condition will look like this:

```
if (playerData[i].nameflags & 0x400000 /* === 0x400000 */)
```

Comment: thx for the answer to this issue.
i also looked in the c++ code for the server its self and found this section.
        FLAG_GM             = 0x04000000,
        FLAG_GM_SUPPORT     = 0x04000000,
        FLAG_GM_SENIOR      = 0x05000000,
        FLAG_GM_LEAD        = 0x06000000,
        FLAG_GM_PRODUCER    = 0x07000000,

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for full bitwise equality of two integers, all you need is just '==' operator, but to use it, you should guarantee that both operands are integers:

```
left = 12323;
right = 12323;
if (left == right)
   alert("Operands are binary equal; I'll guarantee that. :-)");
```

Be very careful though; if at least one of operands is string representing number, not a number, both operands will be considered strings and you can get confusing results:

```
left = "012323";
right = 12323;
if (left != right)
   alert("Operands are not equal, even though they represent 'equal values', as they     are compared as strings.");
```

In general, these days, the attempt to operate with strings representing data instead of data itself is a real curse of the beginners; and it's hard to explain to them. It is especially difficult to explain in JavaScript, with its loose-type typing concept, which is itself very complex and hard to understand, behind the illusory simplicity.

Finally, if you need to compare separate bits (and, from your question, I don't see this need), you can use binary operators:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

That's it, basically.
...................